# Python packages and default/recommended versions

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Let's say I have a package `MyPackage` hosted on Pypi with two versions: `1.0` and `2.0`

When a user runs the command `pip install MyPackage` I want them to download and install `1.0`.
Is it possible to set a default/recommended package version in this manner?

I want to stray away from doing any beta releases i.e. `2.0b1`

Comment: A reasoning for your case would be an unstable package, and a LTS package or something like that ? People usually host a different package, with a different name for this purpose, for instance Tensorflow does this with nightly release. So you might want to go down this path.

Comment: @JeanRostan I also want to stray away from having "beta" versions in general.  I have noticed that the people installing `MyPackage` can tend to be lax about switching off of "beta" versions.  Once a version is found to be suitable, I want to be able to make it the default version.  I don't want my first adopters to have to switch off a "beta" version and on to the identical "production" version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  `pip install MyPackage` will always install the highest available version of `MyPackage`, excluding prelease ("beta") versions unless the `--pre` flag is given.  There are no provisions anywhere in the packaging system for it to do anything else.

Comment: That's a bummer